# git on windows 10 - ssh - bad passphrase

Tags: ssh, windows-10, git

So i tried to set up another remote repository on my machine and have to add the ssh-key to the ssh-agent.

I checked the passphrase of the key with `Puttygen`, so i don't have a typo in the phrase.

I start the `Git bash` and type:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

Then i get the `pid ...` so the agent started correctly.

When i enter the command to add my ssh-key like so:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/somekey.ppk
```

I have to enter the passphrase (i enter the correct passphrase) and i get the following error:

```
Bad passphrase, try again for /c/Users/..../somekey.ppk
```

**Is there some special formatting in Windows 10, can i only use certain characters? I doublechecked the passphrase is the correct one, it works in puttygen... do i have to use a special formatting for the file itself?**

I use SSH-2 RSA with 2048 bits and a 8 character long passphrase with lowercase letters and numbers.

Comment: please refer to this answer: http://superuser.com/questions/1033754/windows-ssh-doesnt-accept-passphrase