# windows ssh doesn't accept passphrase

Tags: windows, ssh, git

I've installed git-for-windows and generated a ssh key with PuTTYgen (with passphrase) and stored it in c:/users/*username*/.ssh/id_rsa.
If I try to log in with putty and enter my passphrase and it works just fine.
But if i try to use `ssh` or `git clone` in the windows shell it doesn't accept my passphrase after `Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/*username*/.ssh/id_rsa'` but just keeps asking for it.
Why doesn't it work with ssh or git?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`openssh` and `PuTTY` are using different key types (but you can convert between them). In PuTTYgen you need to go to `Conversions->Export OpenSSH`, export your private key and store it as `id_rsa`.

More on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2224204/2196426).

Comment: but at my end Export OpenSSh is showing as disabled. If tried to load pk it ask for phrase which is not getting expected by puttygen